# [Stochastics]: What is wrong with dX/X

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Assume that stochastics process for X follows:

$\frac{dX}{X} = \mu dt + \sigma dW$

I know the answer that close form of X is:

$X = e^{(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W(t)}$

However, I dont know what is wrong with the following proof, please help:

$\frac{dX}{X} = d(ln(X)) = \mu dt + \sigma dW$ $

Taking integral on both side:

$ ln(\frac{X}{X_0}) = \mu t + \sigma W(t) $

$ X = X_0 e^{\mu t + \sigma W(t)}$

I am sorry for asking this again. I know that this is a typical mistake but I dont know how to search key word for this.

Thank you

Comment: A short answer: $\frac{dX}{X} \neq d\log(X)$. A correct formula can be obtained by the Itô formula.